# Send an image with CURL

Tags: php, curl

Is it possible to send an image with CURL that outputs with ImagePNG?

```
ob_start();
imagepng(imagecreatetruecolor(800, 600));
$file = ob_get_clean();

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $remoteHost);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, [
    'file1' => ?
]);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to put `@` character before the file path, and the path must be the full path.

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
    'file1' => '@' . '/var/tmp/img.png'
));
```

If the request accepts the image inside the POST body as raw data, that case you can just place it inside the `POST` with mentioning whatever content-type it requires.

```
$image_data = file_get_contents('/var/tmp/img.png');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $image_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain'));  // just an example
```